# How to create a Date with specific format in Java?

Tags: java, string, datetime, date

I have the following code to handle date

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"); 

String s = formatter.format(formatter.parse("10/11/2011 4:24:00 PM");
System.out.prinln(s);
Date d = (Date)formatter.parseObject(s);
System.out.println(d);
```

this first print line output is : `10/10/2011 00:00:00 AM`

and the second is : `Mon Oct 10 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2011`

How I can make the second statement print out the same as the first one?

### edit

the question is how to create date object with this format ?

Comment: This is already the third similar question today: Data->String->Date??

Comment: The question "how to create date object with this format" is nonsensical.  The output you want is created by formatting a `Date` object using a DateFormat object (per Bozho's answer).

Comment: You must distinguish between the object itself (the date) and the correspondig formatting. The latter is in fact only a view that may vary depending on the environment (e.g. user language in a web application).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The `toString()` method of objects is used mainly for debugging, and not for presenting to users.

Always use a formatter. In your case: `String formatted = formatter.format(d)`

The `Date` object does not have a representation format. It only has the data. The formatter has the format.